# Directory changes when being read from text file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file, done.txt which contains paths of files that I need to do something with.
Here is the first part of my done.txt:

```
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_009.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_010.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_013.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_014.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_015.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_020.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_025.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_026.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_027.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_030.flac

.....
```

When I run this command:

```
while IFS= read -r var
do
echo "$var" 
done < /data/voice/done.txt
```

I get exactly things in done.txt:

```
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_009.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_010.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_013.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_014.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_015.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_020.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_025.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_026.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_027.flac
/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_030.flac

....
```

However, when I try:

```
while IFS= read -r var
do
mv "$var" /data/voice #move all files to this directory
done < /data/voice/done.txt
```

I get tons of directory-related errors like this one:

```
mv: cannot stat '/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_009.flac\r': No such file and directory
mv: cannot stat '/data/voice/Voice27Folds/1000/1017_013.flac\r': No such file and directory

...
```

I notice that the correct directories might have changed with "\r" appended to the end. How can I fix that?

Comment: Convert your input file from DOS to UNIX format.

Comment: And don't trust `echo` to tell you things truthfully.

Comment: Even the POSIX specification for `echo`, at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, advises using `printf` instead -- see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections. (Though the particular situation here requires non-POSIX extensions to `printf`).

Comment: ...and btw, separating filenames with newlines is not generally a great idea: Filenames on UNIX are actually allowed to contain newline literals. For instance, one could `touch $'foo\nbar'`, and then you have a file that has a literal newline inside it. For that reason, it's safer to separate filenames in a stream with NUL characters, which can't ever exist inside names.

Answer (score 3):

`$'\r'` is a carriage return -- an instruction to send the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

On DOS (and Windows), each line of a text file ends with `$'\r\n'` (CRLF), whereas on UNIX, each line ends only with `$'\n'`. Thus, when reading a DOS text file on UNIX, each line appears to have an extra `$'\r'`.

Because when `echo` prints that character it moves the cursor to the beginning of the line instead of creating any kind of visible output, the presence of a trailing carriage return situation cannot be distinguished with `echo "$var"` (unless you printed anything after it -- `echo "[$var]"` would put the `]` at the beginning of the line instead of the end). If you want to print variable contents in a visually unambiguous way that shows hidden characters, use `printf 'var=%q\n' "$var"` instead.

```
while IFS= read -r var; do
  var=${var%$'\r'}         # remove any trailing carriage return from var
  mv -- "$var" /data/voice #move all files to this directory
done < /data/voice/done.txt
```

Comment: i have the same problem. I am creating a text file of three columns. I am using bash on window by using osgeo. When i am creating my data into text file in bash i produce ambiguously arrangement of my data set. When i open this text file into nodepad++ it open nicely in three columns format. Please tell me how can i solve the problem of carry return?